# Google location service updates ignoring location listener (android)

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, listener

I have an app which registers a locationClient for updates. However, the location listener never seems to get accessed. The "GPS connected" toast appears, so I know the GPS connects ok, but the toast displaying the coordinates does not display, and the listener being activated is not logged. However, "location updates activated" is logged. 
"connector" is an object which initiates an Asynctask to get database data. It works fine.

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) 
{
    Toast.makeText(context, "GPS connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    connector = new Connector();
    connector.execute("clues", null, null);
    listener = new LocationListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
        {
            Log.d("location", "listener activated");
            try
            {
            double[] coords = locationCoords(location);
            if(coords[0] != 0)
            {
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(coords[0], coords[1]), (float) 14.5));

            }
            Toast.makeText(context, coords[0] + ", " + coords[1], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            catch(NullPointerException e)
            {
                Log.d("nulls", "null");
            }

        }
    };
    mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, listener);
    Log.d("location", "location updates initiated");
}
```

This is the log of the relevant bits. "map null" is logging a different issue, which is that my google maps fragment is not yet initialized when I try to instantiate it.

```
07-12 15:15:36.608: D/dalvikvm(1116): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 133K, 9% free 3105K/3392K, paused 46ms, total 49ms
07-12 15:15:36.618: I/dalvikvm-heap(1116): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.757MB for 635812-byte allocation
07-12 15:15:36.688: D/dalvikvm(1116): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 3726K/4016K, paused 65ms, total 65ms
07-12 15:15:36.818: D/dalvikvm(1116): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2K, 7% free 3742K/4016K, paused 8ms+6ms, total 130ms
07-12 15:15:37.208: D/null(1116): map null
07-12 15:15:37.228: D/location(1116): location request constructed
07-12 15:15:37.368: D/null(1116): map null
07-12 15:15:38.198: D/dalvikvm(1116): GC_CONCURRENT freed 141K, 7% free 3994K/4260K, paused 6ms+59ms, total 252ms
07-12 15:15:38.478: D/libEGL(1116): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
07-12 15:15:38.519: D/(1116): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a19b220, tid 1116
07-12 15:15:38.559: D/libEGL(1116): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
07-12 15:15:38.608: D/libEGL(1116): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
07-12 15:15:39.008: W/EGL_emulation(1116): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-12 15:15:39.068: D/OpenGLRenderer(1116): Enabling debug mode 0
07-12 15:15:39.258: D/(1116): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a1b0310, tid 1140
07-12 15:15:39.268: I/Choreographer(1116): Skipped 93 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-12 15:15:40.028: D/dalvikvm(1116): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 345K, 12% free 4030K/4564K, paused 95ms, total 106ms
07-12 15:15:40.398: D/dalvikvm(1116): GC_CONCURRENT freed 328K, 11% free 4179K/4696K, paused 10ms+13ms, total 130ms
07-12 15:15:41.248: D/location(1116): location updates initiated
07-12 15:15:41.268: D/dalvikvm(1116): GC_CONCURRENT freed 611K, 17% free 4084K/4864K, paused 7ms+61ms, total 340ms
```

This log is from an emulator, but the same behavior happens on a real device.

Comment: Are you using a SupportMapFragment or mapfragment?>

Comment: Well, I thought I'd make this question about the GPS. But I'm using a SupportMapFragment. The map displays ok, I just can't instantiate an object representing it in code.

Comment: Well, the class in the xml is a supportmapfragment, but it seems to just have fragment tags... 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/googlemap"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment">
    

</fragment>

Comment: Can you add the entire map layout xml.  It seems like the map is null because you haven't gotten the map fragment.

Comment: That was the xml of it above. This is the code that instantiates it. 

try
  {
  mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googlemap)).getMap();
  mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
  }
  catch(NullPointerException e)
  {
   Log.d("null", "map null");
  }

Comment: You should be using the getSupportFragmentManager instead view my code below.

Comment: So did that work for ya?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically right before I call and use GoogleMap I instantiate the supportfragmentmanager then use this to instantiate the map.  Like below I hope this helps.

```
    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    SupportMapFragment mf= (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);


    map = mf.getMap();

    //map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    ll = new SecondPointLocationListener();
```

As far as your method for printing the location use this instead...

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) 
{
    Toast.makeText(context, "GPS connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    connector = new Connector();
    connector.execute("clues", null, null);
    listener = new LocationListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
        {
            Log.d("location", "listener activated");
            try
            {
            double[] coords = locationCoords(location);
            if(coords[0] != 0)
            {
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(coords[0], coords[1]), (float) 14.5));

            }

            Double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            Double longitude = location.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText(context,"Latitude = "+ latitude + "" +"Longitude  "+ longitude,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            catch(NullPointerException e)
            {
                Log.d("nulls", "null");
            }

        }
    };
    mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, listener);
    Log.d("location", "location updates initiated");
```

Comment: I used mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googlemap)).getMap(); and it seems to have removed the null error thanks! Must have just been a silly mistake of trying to get it like it was a normal fragment instead of a support fragment.

Comment: Does that mean others won't answer the main question about the GPS listener though?

Comment: Well what is your question about the gps?  You only listed the null pointer

Comment: The GPS listener is never called. The log files show a lack of any logs that should show it has been.

Comment: Actually nevermind. The listener magically started working as soon as the map was initialised properly... not exactly sure why, but I guess the issue is solved.

Comment: Yeah it was the mapfragment that was breaking it.